# Fixing "Error: creation of data source failed (OGR error:Failed to create directory .shp for shapefile datastore.)"

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ogr, error

I am trying to convert from decimal degrees to meters in QGIS. I have a shapefile that is currently in WGS84/UTM zone 19S. I have tried the save as - browse - WGS84 EPSG:4326 but this appears:

> Export to vector file failed. Error: creation of data source failed
> (OGR error:Failed to create  directory .shp for shapefile datastore.)

Does anybody have any ideas? Or any other way of doing it?

I am using QGIS 2.2.0

Comment: Hmmm, I just did a quick test and was able to save just fine from 19S to WGS84.  Perhaps you need to check the directory and name of the new shapefile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify a file name for the export.

In that case, QGIS tries to add ".shp" to a blank file name, which causes the error message you get.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm new to QGIS. What you you mean by the file name. Can you give me an example of what I should put?

Comment: If you mean just title it it still doesn't seem to work. I put meter so it would save meter.shp and still the same message.

Comment: You have to use the "Browse" next to the filename field to select the folder where the file should be written to.

Comment: OK got it, thanks. The reason for doing this was so that I could read the x and y co ordinates as meters. However, when I use the identify features button it still reads them in decimal degrees. Any idea what i've done wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A shapefile in UTM should have coordinates in metres, while EPSG:4326 sould have degrees. Note that coordinates are independent from values written in the attribute table.

Comment: Yep I think they are in meters. I don't quite know what was happening. Just to check, I have coordinates as 686013/7535733. This is meters isn't it?

Comment: If this should be in the South of Departamento de Potosi, yes.

Comment: Thanks Andre, it sure is supposed to be :D So thankful for your help!

Comment: I've been using QGIS professionally for years and still google this error from time to time. It's quite strange that it doesn't prompt you in a more constructive way, such as asking for a destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your orijinal data is not in UTM. Becuse your file need to be in meters in such case. Utm is in meter originally you need to check your initial datum. When you transform to wgs84 it will still be in degrees.