# OGR error: file location not a directory

Tags: qgis, csv, ogr, geocoding, mmqgis

I have an Excel file that I converted to CSV. Then I used MMQGIS to geocode CSV with web service. Then I use the OpenStreetMap as the type of web service. I make sure the to be converted file is going to the right folder. Once I've applied it and it finished converting it tells me:

> Failure creating output file: Creation of data source failed (OGR
> error: H:\Mijn
> documenten\GIS\Projects\1.KGV\Shapefile\Clubhuizen\clubhuizen.shp is
> not a directory.).

I checked the CSV file and its exactly the same as my another file that I geocoded succesfully. What went wrong?

Comment: I guess that you are using ogr2ogr. Could you show the whole command?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  As mentioned in the other comments, please [edit] your question to include details about what you've actually tried, and how you did it.  You can click [edit] here in my comment, or using the link below your question.

Comment: Is the path you want to save the output to empty - or does it already contain a file with the same name? Try saving it to an empty folder. An check if you don't have any non-ascii characters included, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382550/88814

Comment: Your error `H:\Mijn documenten\GIS\Projects\1.KGV\Shapefile\Clubhuizen\clubhuizen.shp is not a directory` tells it: You have chosen a file, where a folder is expected. Choose a folder (without filename) as output destination. Also the dot `.` in your filepath might be an issue for some providers, dont know how MMQGIS handles this. If my first suggestion does not solve it, try a path without special characters like a dot or whitespace.

Comment: I tried taking the special characters away but it didnt change. I also tried to choose a folder without a file name but it gives the error of unsupported filename..

Comment: Do you have permission to write in that folder? Maybe you forgot to specify a file name for the export, see this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93300/how-to-fix-error-creation-of-data-source-failed-ogr-errorfailed-to-create-di

Comment: Try to save it to this path ( add a folder `output`): `H:\output` to be sure the path is valid. Make sure you have writing permission on drive H. Include error message if that doesn't work.